# Error Unresolved attribute reference 'pushButton' for class in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I am working on `pyqt5` project where I am designing the ui in `qt designer` and writing its python code in `pycharm`. Ui has a button and label. Once button is clicked, label value is changed. Below is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class ROCKET(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ROCKET, self).__init__()
        loadUi('ui/gui.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)

    def btn_click(self):
        self.label.setText("CLICKED")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = ROCKET()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pycharm gives warning for `pushButton` and `label`:

`Unresolved attribute reference 'pushButton' for class 'ROCKET'`

but if I am running the code, I am getting correct output. How can I remove these warnings and make the code correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can refer to your widgets as attributes of the main window is a convenience that is offered by PyQt5 via `loadUi`. PyCharm is complaining because it didn't see you explicitly define the `pushButton` attribute for your class.

One way you can get around the warning would be to explicitly define the attribute:

```
self.pushButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "name_of_push_button")
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)
```

Comment: An important note: this will only *clear* the warnings. But they are ***just*** warnings, caused by the dynamic nature of UI loading (the IDE cannot know the type of the new attribute, nor resolve its internal attributes). I strongly suggest against doing the above, as it will only make the code cumbersome (and do something that is programmatically unnecessary and inefficient, since uic already creates those attributes). Keep the warnings, or ignore them with the appropriate PyCharm function.